# Python PyQt5 Изменение положения окна по горячим клавишам

Tags: python, pyqt5, keypressevent, геометрия, closeevent

У меня 2 вопроса по библиотеке *PyQt5*.

1. Хочу создать свойство при инициализации объекта класса `Dialog(QWidget)` , с возможностью изменять положение окна по горячим клавишам (стрелки клавиатуры).
2. Как мне сохранить последнее положение и размер окна , чтобы при перезапуске приложения вызываемое окно открывалось в последней точке нахождения на рабочем столе.

Вот мой пример кода:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget

class Dialog(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.posX = None  # позиция x
        self.posY = None  # позиция y
        self.posW = None  # позиция w
        self.posH = None  # позиция h

        self.old_pos = None  # Прошлая позиция

        self.setWindowTitle('Dialog')  # имя
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 220)  # Геометрия
        self.setWindowOpacity(0.5)  # Прозрачность
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.CustomizeWindowHint)  # окно без кнопок , можно менять размер
```

Comment: 2) Сохранить либо в файле либо в реестре, смотрите в сторону QSettings, либо же можно сохранять в JSON

Comment: 1) Не вижу тут проблем, просто переопределить функцию https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#keyPressEvent

Answer (score 0):

1. Надо переопределить метод `keyPressEvent`
2. Как вариант(самый простой для вас способ) -
   сохранять то что вам надо, а надо вам всего ничего,
   в файл, например `geometry.ini`.
   **Обратите внимание**, чтобы сохранять нужные значени,
   вам нужно переопределить метод `closeEvent`.

---

```
import os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QLabel, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont


class Dialog(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = 300                                 # позиция по оси x
        self.y = 300                                 # позиция по оси y
        self.w = 300                                 # ширина
        self.h = 220                                 # высота
        
        # 'geometry.ini' - файл для сохранения последнее положение и размер окна    
        self.fileName = 'geometry.ini'
        if os.path.exists(self.fileName):
            with open(self.fileName, 'r') as f:
                self._geometry = map(int, f.read().strip().split())
        else:
            self._geometry = [self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h]  

        self.setWindowTitle('Dialog')                # имя Title
        self.setGeometry(* self._geometry)           # Геометрия
        self.setWindowOpacity(0.5)                   # Прозрачность
        
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.CustomizeWindowHint)  # окно без кнопок , можно менять размер
        
        self.key_label = QLabel(alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.key_label)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):                        
        x = self.pos().x()
        y = self.pos().y()
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Up:
            self.key_label.setText('Key Up Pressed')
            self.move(x, y-10)
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_Down:
            self.key_label.setText('Key Down Pressed')
            self.move(x, y+10)
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_Left:
            self.key_label.setText('Key Left Pressed')
            self.move(x-10, y)
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_Right:
            self.key_label.setText('Key Right Pressed')
            self.move(x+10, y)
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.close()
            
    def closeEvent(self, event):  
        geometry = f"{self.geometry().x()} {self.geometry().y()} {self.geometry().width()} {self.geometry().height()}"
        with open(self.fileName, 'w') as f:
            f.write(geometry)      
      

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 12, QFont.Bold))
    w = Dialog()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

С событиями решил сам так :

```
def keyPressEvent(self, e):
    if e.key() == Qt.Key_Escape:
        self.close()
    if e.key() == Qt.Key_Up:
        self.resize(self.size().width(), self.height() + 1)
    if e.key() == Qt.Key_Down:
        self.resize(self.size().width(), self.height() - 1)
    if e.key() == Qt.Key_Left:
        self.resize(self.size().width() - 1, self.height())
    if e.key() == Qt.Key_Right:
        self.resize(self.size().width() + 1, self.height())
    if e.key() == Qt.Key_8:
        self.move(self.pos().x(), self.pos().y() - 1)
    if e.key() == Qt.Key_2:
        self.move(self.pos().x(), self.pos().y() + 1)
    if e.key() == Qt.Key_4:
        self.move(self.pos().x() - 1, self.pos().y())
    if e.key() == Qt.Key_6:
        self.move(self.pos().x() + 1, self.pos().y())
```

C настройками буду пробовать , спасибо за ответ...

Comment: а ничего страшного, что я вам ответ написал 5 часов назад? Может мне надо убрать свой ответ, чтобы не мешать вам пробовать настройку ?